# Select percentage of rows that have a certain value - SQL

Tags: sql, count

Say I have a table like this in Sequel Pro:

```
SaleID    VendorID
1             A
2             C
3             E
4             C
5             D
```

And I want to find the percentage of sales in which Vendor C was the vendor. (Obviously in this case it is 40%, but I'm working with much bigger tables). How would I do that? I was thinking something using the `Count` function, but I'm not sure how I would do it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I know ideally I wouldn't have letters for the IDs, but the actual values in my table are strings of letters, not numbers.

Answer (score 23):

```
select sum(case when vendorID = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*)
from your_table
```

Comment: `sum(vendorID = 'C') * 100 / count(*)` is much shorter btw :)

Comment: @Markus: That works in MySQL but not in most other DBs. And since that isn't tagged MySQL ...

Comment: The OP states using `Sequel Pro` which uses MySQL-syntax -Thus, it is a valid shortcut (btw. the tag `sql` also does also not speak against this solution). Anyhow, it is always necessary to check what your db supports, this is also true :) For stating "_most_" I'd like to see a source for this; I experienced it the other way around (at least for any technology from the last ten years).

Comment: @Markus: Just check for yourself with other systems like Oracle and SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/. The mayor DB systems do NOT support that.