# SQL for calculating percentage of values for same column

Tags: php, sql

### what is the SQL for calculating the sum of a value in one column for a certain condition in other column(sum of value in column 1 for certain value in column 2 )and calculating the sum of all values in column 1 (sum of all values in column 1) and calculating the percentage as (sum of value in column 1 for certain value in column 2/sum of all values in column 1)*100?

### i have two columns A and B.

### A has values (1,2,3,4) and

### B has values say (1,0,1,0).

### 1)sum of value in column 1 for certain value in column 2 means

i have to find the sum of all values in A where value of B is 1(1,3)which is(4) and

### 2)sum of all values in column 1 means

sum of all values of A(which is 10).

### 3)calculating the percentage as (sum of value in column 1 for certain value in column 2/sum of all values in column 1)*100 means

((1)/(2))*100
in this case it is(4/10)*100=(40%).

Comment: If you add examples and expected output it wouldn't be so complicated

Comment: And what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes an example would have been great. Just by what you have written the solution seems to be like a subquery with a sum of that column, and then you can calculate the percentage.

Comment: am sorry for not including the example in the question .it is much like a sub query.i have two columns A and B  A has values (1,2,3,4) and B has values say (1,0,1,0).sum of value in column 1 for certain value in column 2 means i have to find  the sum of all values in A  where value of B is 1(1,3)which is(4) and        sum of all values in column 1       
 sum of all values of A(which is 10).total percentage is(4/10)*100=(40%). thank you all for the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(case when Column2 = 'somevalue' then Column1 else 0 end) * 100 / sum(Column1) from NAMES;
```

See this:-

[Select percentage of rows that have a certain value - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191243/select-percentage-of-rows-that-have-a-certain-value-sql)